# Requirement for turning sum into integral

Tags: integration, calculus

Following a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312984/) about turning a sum to an integral,

Say we are summing over discrete points $\mathbf k$ in k-space $$\sum_\mathbf{k}\ f(\mathbf k)\ .$$

We can use *the definition of the Riemann
integral*
\begin{align}
\sum_{\mathbf k} f(\mathbf k) &= \frac{1}{\Delta k} \sum_{\mathbf k}
f(\mathbf k) \Delta k \\
&\equiv \frac{1}{\Delta k}  \int_{\mbox{all space}} f(\mathbf k) d\mathbf k
\ ,
\end{align}
where, in the last step we used our assumption that our seperation
distance is negligibly small compared to the volume of the whole
space.

My question is:

1. Why is the ${\Delta k} << all space$ in order for the equation to work?
   I understand the Riemann sum and that the separation distance must be very small, but I don't understand why the whole volume is a factor..
   My guess would be that it should be much smaller then some function of the derivative of ${f(k)}$ since it determines how accurate the sum will be.
2. I'd like to understand how can I approximate my error.
   In the above example there can be an equality **iff**  ${\Delta k} \to 0 $.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to treat the $1D$ case for simplicity, but this generalizes easily.

The Riemann sum $\Delta k\sum_k f(k)$ converges to $\int f(k)\text dk$ in the limit $\Delta k\to 0$. To prove this, consider a small cell $D_k$ of length $\Delta k$ around each value of $k$ in the sum. Then, you have :
$$\int f(k') \text dk' = \sum_k \int_{D_k}f(k')\text dk'$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\left|\int f(k')\text dk' - \Delta k \sum_kf(k)\right| & =\left| \sum_k\int_{D_k}f(k')\text dk' - \Delta k f(k)\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{k} \left| \int_{D_k}f(k')\text dk' - \Delta k f(k)\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{k}  \int_{D_k}\left|f(k')-f(k) \right| \text dk' \\
\end{align}

If the derivative of $f$ is bounded by some $M>0$, then, we have for $k'\in D_k$, $ |f(k')-f(k)|\leq M \Delta k$. Then, we find :
$$\left|\int f(k')\text dk' - \Delta k \sum_kf(k)\right| \leq VM\Delta k $$
where $V$ is the volume of space.